# Save information from a class into another module and have them affect each other

Tags: python

```
import random


names = ["buffycarrot", "minidiscscutum", "bromidethousand", "potassiumkiva",
         "tamarinenglish", "galliumreproduce","chollywhisky", "waspgermless",
         "annesketch", "channelslaldy", "melbagenius", "lebanesewapiti",
         "monologuepseudo", "albatrosswashington", "ferrisclutch", "moistosdale",
         "granbymixin", "tuxaustrina","diffuserdraw", "pebblecricket", "smilegila",
         "bornedeclair", "sixfoldexcitable", "apricotgangles", "portalensemble",
         "spritsailreduce", "corruptlabcoat", "glowinggrant", "goslingwillow",
         "creoleascender",  "samefee", "omegatarbert", "waggerboned", "seniorglimmer",
         "analyzepale", "sickoeye", "cartloadmoors", "broadlyselfie",
         "interferepurely", "grostynethan", "mendeleviumweird", "supermombangin",
         "gashpanicky", "periodprivate", "possetpastor", "bannerrosti", "reamerchex",
         "punkfeline", "poachedkarate", "cupcakegrin"]

def random_name(name_count):
        username = ""
        names_used = []
        for name in names:
            if name not in names_used:
                chosen_name = ""
                chosen_name += names[name_count]
                names_used += chosen_name
                return chosen_name
            else:
                name_count += 1
```

Problem is that the `username` and `name_used` reset every time I run the code in another module.
When I write: `print(x.random_name)` it comes out as `buffycarrot`, doing it again will prove the same thing instead of the `minidiscscutum` intended from the next line in the dictionary. Please revise my code or tell me the necessary tools and lines to accomplish this.

Comment: Your title and code seem to have very little to do with each other. The code doesn't involve classes or modules, so the title seems to be a total non-sequitur. Is your question about how to get random names from a list without replacement, or something about modules?

Answer (score 1):

The variables within a function are local, which means they only exist within the function. To make them global, use the `global` keyword. 
For example, in the code below, `my_function` prints 3 but the `print(a)` prints 0.

```
a = 0

def my_function():
    a = 3
    print(a)

my_function()

print(a)
```

Output:

```
3
0
```

If you use `global`, you can change the variable from local to global.

```
a = 0

def my_function():
    global a
    a = 3
    print(a)

my_function()

print(a)
```

Output:

```
3
3
```

Converting the variables `username` and `name_used` from local to global should let them store information from a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

names = [
    "buffycarrot",
    "minidiscscutum",
    "bromidethousand",
    # ...
]


def random_name():
    candidates = names[:]
    while candidates:
        cand = random.choice(candidates)
        yield cand
        candidates.remove(cand)


# in other module
for name in random_name():
    print(name)
```

you want to keep the global state, [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) is the choice.